# In javascript how to call dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have mentioned the code below:

```
     function driveInfo(linkSpeed,serialNo, modelNo, bootLoader, lightSwitch, twidlVersion)
    {

        $('#linkSpeed').html(linkSpeed);
        $('#serialNumber').html(serialNo);
        $('#modelNumber').html(modelNo);
        $('#bootLoader').html(bootLoader);
        $('#lightSwitch').html(lightSwitch);
        $('#twidlVersion').html(twidlVersion);
        $dialog.dialog('open');

    }
    var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 200,
                        width:500,
                        modal: true,
                        position: {
                            my: "bottom+200",
                            at: "bottom",
                            of: $("tbody"),
                            within: $("tbody")
                            },
                    });
```

In php side dialog box Code:

```
printf( '<div id="dialog"  title="Drive Info" style="display:none; background: transparent;">' );
printf( '<div class="ui-popup">' );
printf( '<ul style="list-style-type: none;padding: 8px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;">' );
printf( '<li><b>Link Speed:</b>&nbsp;<span id="linkSpeed"></span></li>' );
printf( '<li><b>Serial Number:</b>&nbsp;<span id="serialNumber"></span></li>' );
printf( '<li><b>Model Number:</b>&nbsp;<span id="modelNumber"></span></li>' );
printf( '<li><b>Boot Loader:</b>&nbsp;<span id="bootLoader"></span></li>'   );
printf( '<li><b>LightSwitch Rev:</b>&nbsp;<span id="lightSwitch"></span></li>' );
printf( '<li><b>TWIDL Version:</b>&nbsp;<span id="twidlVersion"></span></li>' );
printf( '</ul>' );
printf( '</div>' );
printf( '</div>' );
```

Calling Function using the below code:

```
printf('<td class="long"><a href="#"
onClick="driveInfo(\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\');
return false;"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a></td>
</tr>',$link,$model,$test,$testing,$help,$model2):
```

I need to display popup dialog box in page.

Please help me how to call the dialog when clicking the function.

Any solution is appreciable.

Comment: Do you get any error on console? What happens now?

Comment: Simply move dialog initialization to function and call it...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting "display:none" on your `<div id="dialog"...` element, set the following option in the dialog options: `autoOpen: false`

e.g.

```
 var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    autoOpen:false,
                    height: 200,
                    //...etc
```

See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated for an example

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial it may help you  [dialogue Box](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)